# The constructor refers to the missing type

Tags: java, eclipse, constructor

I have been trying to solve this particular error in my Java project since many days. I have a hard luck solving this.

I have a class in which one of the methods call another class's method using the constructor. Seems everything is correct but this error is not getting solved. I have tried to clean up the project too. But no luck. Please see the screenshots. First image is the class's method that is calling another class's method.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The import statements are importing the same definition of UIPluginContext

Comment: Where's the library containing the `UIContext` class? If Eclipse thinks it's missing, where should it be looking that it's not already looking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i had the same mistake, i just imported the missing "libraries" with Ctrl+Shift+O and worked